# Spring MVC 3 SimpleFormController

Tags: java, forms, spring-mvc

In Spring 2.5; there is **SimpleFormController** having method

```
    @Override
        protected Object formBackingObject(HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception {
            //logic for command object

}
```

What is its alternative in Spring mvc 3. I want to load command object in a jsp page form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use  @ModelAttribute

```
@ModelAttribute
public MyFormObject createForm(HttpServletRequest request){

}
```

Would work without the request also

```
@ModelAttribute
public MyFormObject createForm(){

}
```